# How remove ul tags and all enclosed contents in JS with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, mobile

how i can remove with js the ul tags and all the content?
example

```
<div>
    <ul>
         <li>a</li>
         <li>b</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i want this

```
<div></div>
```

i use

```
var.replace('regex', '');
```

anyone can help me?

Ps. only js, i can't use Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on a regular expression as the answer, you could use the following.

```
str = str.replace(/\s*<ul[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/ul>\s*/, '');
```

Comment: i test this! 2 minutes and i give you a response ;)

Comment: ok this work!, at last i have modified a bit your regex, i use
/\s*<ul[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/ul>\s*/
because the ul have a class

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex when you can use dom parsing?

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
ul.parentElement.removeChild(ul)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8N2CQ/1/

Comment: because is a titanium mobile project, not a web project. I have a string and i must manipulate this. but thanks.