# Split html including split of ul tag with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am splitting a block of HTML by words using `\b(\w+(?![^<>]*>))\b`

```
var html = splitParagraph.html();
var splitHtml = html.split(/\b(\w+(?![^<>]*>))\b/);
```

The HTML I am doing this on looks something like the following:

```
                <h2>Lorem</h2><br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor<br>
<br>
[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor]<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor:<br>
<ul><br>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor</li><br>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor</li><br>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor</li><br>
</ul><br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor<br>
<br>
```

You can see it working here: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95537

However, what I want to do is make it so that the regex also includes `ul` tags when it splits, so that, in an array, it might look something like `["lorem", " ", "ipsum", "<ul><li>lorem</li><li>ipsum</li><li>blah</li></ul>"]` (note that the ul is its own item). Thus, it would not split anything inside of the `ul`, but just move on to whatever is after the ul.

I know that I can use `\s*<ul[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/ul>\s*` to match the `ul`, (thanks for [the ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542995/how-remove-ul-tags-and-all-enclosed-contents-in-js-with-regex)) but I'm not sure how to combine these two.

Comment: Is this what you want?: `(<ul>[\s\S]*?<\/ul>|\b\w+(?![^<>]*>)\b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `/\<ul\>[\w\W]+\<\/ul\>|\b(\w+(?![^<>]*>))\b/g` , but I'm sure there's a smaller solution, since this one just matches your original plus anything between `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags.

I would advice against using this kind of structure though since it's difficult to maintain or expand upon. Any use case what you'll do with that resulting array? Maybe there's better options.

edit: as shown, you can just join both regexes with the `|`

Comment: I suggest a `?` after `[\w\W]+` as to not glob multiple `<ul>...</ul>` together.